# hosting symfony2 app on azure web app

Tags: php, symfony, azure

i have a problem hosting a symfony2 app on azure. It am always getting an "Failed to write cache file" error in Filesystem.php. I guess that php does not not have the permission to write to the cache folder. How can i give php the permisson to 
modify the cache, without webdeploy or git, i only have ftp and the azure management portal.

KR Manuel

Comment: I am not familiar with azure, but if you have FTP, can't you set var/{logs,sessions,cache} to CHMOD 777?

Comment: As do you have any custom cache path in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the correct directories for logs and cache in your Kernel.
And you can usually set permissions for that folder using your FTP client.

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if ($this->getEnvironment() == 'prod') {
        return 'D:\\home\\data\\cache\\prod';
    }
    return parent::getCacheDir();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    if ($this->getEnvironment() == 'prod') {
        return 'D:\\home\\LogFiles\\app\\';
    }
    return parent::getLogDir();
}
```

there is also a pre-made bundle to take care of these things:
https://github.com/brainsonic/AzureDistributionBundle

and even a detailed tutorial:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html